# Makefile: "No rule to make target..." with multiple working directories

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile

I'm trying to run this makefile, and run into an issue. Make tells me

```
"No rule to make target 'UDP_Server.o', needed by 'SendRawData',
```

Since I've given it the working directories of the files however, shouldn't the rule for %.o file work just fine? I'm launching make within the /thing/asset/src directory, and I don't care where it puts the o files or the program, as long as I can access them. Here's my makefile:

```
CC = g++

INC += -I/home/pi/thing/ 
INC += -I/home/pi/thing/Asset/src/
INC += -I/home/pi/thing/Server/src/
INC += -I/home/pi/thing/Shared/NetworkInterface/src/
INC += -I/home/pi/mercuryapi/c/src/

LIB = /home/pi/mercury/c/src/api/

CFLAGS  = -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings
LDFLAGS = -L$(LIB) -static -l libmercuryapi 

SOURCES += UDP_Client.cpp
SOURCES += UDP_Server.cpp
SOURCES += rawData.cpp
SOURCES += packetMethods.cpp
SOURCES += parseData.cpp
SOURCES += SendRawData.cpp

OBJECTS =  $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

DEPS  = UDP_Client.h
DEPS += UDP_Server.h
DEPS += packet.h
DEPS += rawData.h
DEPS += packetMethods.h
DEPS += parseData.h
DEPS += tm_reader.h

default: SendRawData

%.o: %.cpp $(SOURCES) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@ 

SendRawData: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(INC) $< -o SendRawData

client: cmain.cpp UDP_Client.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) cmain.cpp UDP_Client.cpp -o client

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o
```

If it helps at all, here is the directory structure visualized:

```
/home/pi/thing/
├── Asset
│   ├── README.txt
│   └── src
│       ├── makefile
│       ├── README.txt
│       ├── SendRawData.cpp
│       ├── UDP_Client.cpp
│       └── UDP_Client.h
├── Server
│   └── src
│       ├── README.txt
│       ├── server
│       ├── UDP_Server.cpp
│       ├── UDP_Server.h
│       └── UDP_Server.o
└── Shared
    ├── NetworkInterface
    │   ├── README.txt
    │   └── src
    │       ├── header.h
    │       ├── packet.h
    │       ├── packetMethods.cpp
    │       ├── packetMethods.h
    │       ├── parseData.cpp
    │       ├── parseData.h
    │       ├── rawData.cpp
    │       ├── rawData.h
    │       └── testing.cpp
    └── README.txt
```

Comment: You've given one makefile but your tree says you have multiple, which one is it?

Comment: And *where* are you executing Make? And where do you want it to put the binaries (e.g. `UDP_Client.o` and `SendRawData`)?

Comment: Changed, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Make cares where you put the files. You need to tell make where the source files are located.

The ugly, tedious, but explanatory solution is to add the path when specifying the dependency. Instead of

```
SOURCES += UDP_Client.cpp
```

write

```
SOURCES += ../../Server/src/UDP_Client.cpp
```

The beautiful and simple solution is to use makes VPATH variable:

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html
```

For example

```
VPATH = "../../Server/src/UDP_Client.cpp:<list of : separated paths>"
```

This solution might only work if your using gnu make.